# Understanding Mocking In Jest Tests

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm not brand new to unit tests but I haven't written very many of them.  Can someone explain in the most non computer science terms the point of mocking?  If we mock a function, if someone changes the function but doesn't change the mock how do we actually know the mock is still viable?  The test could pass even if the function fails in the code.   Why don't we always just test the actual implemented function over a mock of that function?

Comment: *The test could pass even if the function fails in the code* - if it's your own function, it needs to be covered with tests as well. If it's third-party, this is what integration/e2e tests are for. *Why don't we always just test the actual implemented function over a mock of that function* - because this increases the number of moving parts and results in less predictable test that is hard to debug. Testing several units together efficiently makes it integration test, which isn't a substitute for unit tests.

Comment: @EstusFlask so is mocking functions only to test dependencies? If I have function(a,b) { return a + b } and I mock it, if someone changes the actual implementation how does my mock know its broken?

Comment: This fn should have been covered by another test. If it fails, this means that any other unit that uses it is affected, someone who fixes the test should update mocks for it as well. Then there should be integration/e2e test that should preferably fail when fn implementation changes in a way it affects other units that depend on it.